# Django add multiple tags html tags

Tags: html, django

Trying to add two html tags, how can I do this in Django html template?

Here is an example:

```
${{ data.price|floatformat:2 and Intcomma }}
```

Need to load this to use the intcomma tag: {% load humanize %}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *chain* the template filters together:

```
{% load humanize %}
${{ data.price|floatformat:2|intcomma }}
```

For example:

```
>>> Template('{% load humanize %}${{ price|floatformat:2|intcomma }}').render(Context({'price': 1425.3}))
'$1,425.30'
>>> Template('{% load humanize %}${{ price|floatformat:2|intcomma }}').render(Context({'price': 1425}))
'$1,425.00'
```

That being said, you might look for a package like [**`django-money`** [readthedocs]](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that will provide more tooling to format money in a more elegant way.